# How do I set CPUminer to Scrypt instead of SHA256?

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin, miner-configuration, cpuminer

I have started litecoin mining with cpuminer on Ubuntu 12.04 and I keep getting
this message.

> PROOF OF WORK: RESULT: false(booooooo)

From what I understand litecoin uses scrypt however my cpuminer is outputting it is using SHA256, how can I change it to use the correct algortmn Here is my shell output.

```
root@falcon1:/home/cpuminer# [2013-12-05 09:14:46] Binding thread 1 to cpu 1
[2013-12-05 09:14:47] 2 miner threads started, using SHA256 '4way' algorithm.
[2013-12-05 09:15:02] thread 0: 16777216 hashes, 1012.62 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:15:03] thread 1: 16777216 hashes, 996.63 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:16:09] thread 1: 59213728 hashes, 936.63 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:16:10] thread 0: 59213728 hashes, 920.90 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:17:09] thread 1: 56394048 hashes, 941.61 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:17:12] thread 0: 55512896 hashes, 893.86 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:18:12] thread 0: 53722176 hashes, 895.46 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:18:13] thread 1: 56394048 hashes, 878.69 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:19:12] thread 1: 52869440 hashes, 895.40 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:19:48] LONGPOLL detected new block
[2013-12-05 09:19:48] thread 0: 33763392 hashes, 892.91 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:19:48] thread 1: 31865344 hashes, 890.19 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:20:25] thread 1: 34381408 hashes, 926.39 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:20:25] PROOF OF WORK RESULT: false (booooo)
[2013-12-05 09:20:45] thread 0: 53310624 hashes, 937.28 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:21:22] thread 1: 55753664 hashes, 977.72 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:21:34] LONGPOLL detected new block
[2013-12-05 09:21:34] thread 0: 49669760 hashes, 1022.35 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:21:34] thread 1: 11517600 hashes, 1021.31 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:22:25] LONGPOLL detected new block
[2013-12-05 09:22:25] thread 0: 50791968 hashes, 982.01 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:22:25] thread 1: 52474560 hashes, 1014.78 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:23:25] thread 0: 58606144 hashes, 981.58 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:23:26] thread 1: 60547584 hashes, 1009.27 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:23:51] LONGPOLL detected new block
[2013-12-05 09:23:51] thread 0: 26034368 hashes, 1011.37 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:23:51] thread 1: 26110848 hashes, 1026.02 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:24:43] LONGPOLL detected new block
[2013-12-05 09:24:43] thread 0: 50636992 hashes, 966.79 khash/sec
[2013-12-05 09:24:43] thread 1: 53279776 hashes, 1017.50 khash/sec
```